# Call member function that can be reached by implicit conversion in C++

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, reference-wrapper

Trying to create a reference wrapper similar to std::reference_wrapper, but with possibility to call the methods of the wrapped object.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    void f() {
         std::cout << "A::f()\n";
    }
};

class WrapA {
public:
    WrapA(A& a) : _a_ptr{&a} {}

    operator A&() {
        return *_a_ptr;
    }
private:
    A* _a_ptr;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    WrapA wrap{a};

    wrap.f();                  // Fails with compile error: ‘class WrapA’ has no member named ‘f’
    static_cast<A>(wrap).f();  // Works

    return 0;
}
```

Why calling class A function f() on the wrapper object doesn't work, although implicit conversion from WrapA to A is possible? Is there some way to work around this issue?

Tried using std::reference_wrapper and it fails with same compile error.

Comment: Conversions are never considered when figuring out how to resolve a call to a member function. `foo.some_function()` will always be based on the (possibly dynamic) type of `foo`, not some other object `foo` could be converted to.

Comment: Implicit conversion is not performed when the dot operator is used.

Answer (score 3):

One way to get this type of behavior is to overload the arrow operator `operator ->` and have it return a pointer to the wrapped object.  That will get applied recursively by the compiler on the returned pointer and let you call the member function.  That would give you

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    void f() {
         std::cout << "A::f()\n";
    }
};

class WrapA {
public:
    WrapA(A& a) : _a_ptr{&a} {}

    A* operator ->() {
        return _a_ptr;
    }
private:
    A* _a_ptr;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    WrapA wrap{a};

    wrap->f();
    
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs

```
A::f()
```

and you can see it working in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4df2969f8fd23ca6).

Comment: Is there a possibility to override the operator dot (.)? So that `wrap.f()` would work?

Comment: @IsraelYankelovich You cannot overload `operator .`

Answer (score 0):

You asked

> Why calling class A function f() on the wrapper object doesn't work, although implicit conversion from WrapA to A is possible?

The standard specifies the contexts in which implicit conversion can take place (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/conv#2):

> 2 [ *Note*: expressions with a given type will be implicitly converted to other  types in several contexts:
>
> (2.1) -- When used as operands of operators. The operator's requirements for its operands dictate the destination type (Clause [expr]).
>
> (2.2) -- When used in the condition of an if statement or iteration statement  ([stmt.select], [stmt.iter]). The destination type is bool.
>
> (2.3) -- When used in the expression of a switch statement. The destination type is integral ([stmt.select]).
>
> (2.4) -- When used as the source expression for an initialization (which includes use as an argument in a function call and use as the expression in a return statement). The type of the entity being initialized is (generally) the destination type. See [dcl.init], [dcl.init.ref].
>
> — *end note* ]

Please note that using an object in a dot operator is not one of them.